# Does a custom UserControl have to be compiled to an OCX?

Tags: user-controls, vb6

this is a pretty n00b question, but i cant seem to find the 'right answer', and i have looked ALL over..

**(vb6)**.. But i found a Custom User Control (.ctl & .ctx file Source) that wraps the MSComm control... (i also have a custom button control Source)

instead of compiling it as an .ocx and having to include it as a separate file...
or as a .dll

can i just include the controls in my project and throw the control on my form and include it that way, without having to distribute a separate .ocx or .dll after i compile ??

i am asking because when i finish, will i have to distribute **ANY** other files or just  .exe          ??

Could someone please explain to me how this works ? i dont want to have to distribute any other files just my prog.exe

(and the user control for MSComm is a wrapper, i need it because, i cant seem to get around the MSComm 16 port limit, i need higher)

Thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a .ctl and .ctx file in your project then they are built into the executable just like any other .frm or .bas. If they reference an external file (like MSComm) then that file will have to be on any destination machine (one way or another).  IF the destination machine does not have MSComm then you will have to distribute it AND register it (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219)

Comment: Thank you, Thats what i wanted to know... everybody nowadays has "Microsoft Comm Control 6.0 - MSCOMM32.OCX" by default right ? from XP on up ??

Comment: Maybe not: http://www.utex.com/webapps/utexsupport.nsf/wPages/MSZI-856MAG2615?Open

Comment: There are plenty of ways in which things you expect to be present on the computer you are deploying to can be missing or not installed / registered properly. Your installer ideally ought to check for its dependencies and install them if they are needed.